# Why is AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist always returning true?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to check if an S3 bucket exists.

Looking through the AWS API for .NET I found [AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3UtilDoesS3BucketExistIS3String.html) 
which I thought is exactly what I needed.

Although it returns true for buckets I know exist unfortunately it also returns true if the bucket does not exist.

I am connecting to the AWS account via an IAM user; I am confident this works as other functionality such as listing buckets and their contents works without an issue.

Here is a sample console application:

```
using System;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Amazon.S3.Util;

namespace S3FileSystemSample1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string bucketName = "realbucket"; // returns true which is expected
            string bucketName = "randombucket"; // also returns true which is not expected.

            TransferUtility _transferUtility = new TransferUtility();

            bool bucketExists = AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(_transferUtility.S3Client, bucketName);

            if(bucketExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket DOES NOT Exists");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: What Intellisense displays
[image]

In this example, I have created the AmazonS3Client in a different manner but without success - it continues to return true.

```
using System;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Util;

namespace S3FileSystemSample1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string bucketName = "realbucket";
            string bucketName = "randombucket";

            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

            bool bucketExists = AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(client, bucketName);

            if (bucketExists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bucket DOES NOT Exists");
            }            
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: does intellisense show "DoesS3BucketExist" using "client, name" or "name, client?" ... I would think it'd throw an error if types weren't expected, but maybe not and it freaks out and just returns true? I referenced this for parameters - I'm not familiar with the function though so their docs may be wrong, or it may have changed or something:
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Util_AmazonS3Util_DoesS3BucketExist.htm

Comment: Thanks, I think you are on the correct track. The s3client type I am passing is probably incorrect, I will look into this further. I've updated the question to illustrate what Intellisense displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because bucket names are [globally unique](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html). In this case `randombucket` is actually a real bucket. This returns true for me:-

```
private static void DoesBucketExist(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint)
{
    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, regionEndpoint))
    {
        var doesS3BucketExist = AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(client, "randombucket");
        Console.WriteLine(doesS3BucketExist);
    }
}
```

Whereas this does not:-

```
private static void DoesBucketExist(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint)
{
    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, regionEndpoint))
    {
        var doesS3BucketExist = AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(client, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(doesS3BucketExist);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Edit* You can further confirm this by visiting http://randombucket.s3.amazonaws.com/ and you'll see that you get an `Access Denied` whereas if you visit http://50820dfd-428d-47ff-879e-dbcac3acf139.s3.amazonaws.com/ you get `NoSuchBucket`.